# Problems with a new Directory Android 5.1

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

`enter code here`I need create a new file .xml in Android, but in versions like Lollipop or Kitkat it's not working.
In other versions I can save in my files creating a directory called Dive.
Now when a use this code:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

This value is returned:

```
/storage/emulated/0/MyApp
```

I am unable to create a new directory in the latest versions.

My user need acess and copy this file after generated.

```
    XStream y = new XStream();
    String adress = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Dive/logbook_" + ID + ".xml";
    File file = new File(adress);
    FileOutputStream rec;
    try {
        rec = new FileOutputStream(file);
        rec.write(y.toXML(log).toString().replace(".", ",").getBytes());
        rec.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the whole code you are usin to create the file ?

Comment: Are you understand my problem?

Comment: Seems a bit confusing... Let's go step by step.
When you do :
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Dive/logbook_" + ID + ".xml").createNewFile();
Can you see the new created file in the right directory ?

Comment: Sorry, now you can see the code to better, my code was in Portuguese. In the folder storage/emulated exists only a file with name "0" and witohut type.